# How prepare dataset for CONVLSTM2D?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to use CONVLSTM2D in keras but I don't know how to prepare and ingress the training data. I don't know if the input data is one image with the frame sequence to learn or an image cell (as matlab).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned about frames, I am assuming that you want to train model on videos. For videos you can convert video to single numpy file and train model as mentioned below in sample code snippet.

```
>>> np.load('dataset/scene_0.npy').shape()
(1000, 3, 400, 400)
>>> np.load('dataset/category_0.npy').shape()
(6, 1, 1000, 1)
```

Then you need to use generator which feeds the model sample by sample using .fit_generator().

You can find detailed information about this topic [here](https://medium.com/neuronio/an-introduction-to-convlstm-55c9025563a7)